# Получить значение всех элементов $_GET, не зная точное их количество

Tags: php, get

На моём сайте пользователь должен указать в форме имена домашних питомцев. Если у него один домашний питомец - он заполняет лишь один input name="name1"
Но он может добавлять два, три, десять полей ввода
У каждого нового inqut'a в имени добавляется порядковый номер:

```
name="name1"
name="name2"
name="name3"
```

После отправки формы мне нужно обработать каждого питомца и добавить его в базу данных
Как я могу перебрать циклом все инпуты?

Я пробовал так, но у меня не работает:

```
$i = 1;
while ($check)
{
    if (isset($_GET['name'.$i]))
    {
     $name = $_GET['name'.$i];
     //Добавляем $name в бд
    }
    else 
    {
     $check = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: name = "name[]" и просто обработаете массив

Comment: Здравствуйте! name = "name[]", это где нужно написать? Не совсем понятно

Comment: во всех  `<input`

Comment: Благодарю, не знал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если во всех `input` в конце каждого имени добавить квадратные скобки вот так:

```
<input name="name[]"  />
                 ^^--------
```

то на бэк все значения прилетят в виде массива с именем `name`

(посмотрите внутрь переменной `$_GET['name']`)

Который можно обработать как угодно - циклом или ещё как

Comment: Отлично. Благодарю!